# SWIFT Can't get Route between two points on GoogleMaps

Tags: ios, swift

After obtaining two location coordinates (the starting point and the end point) I tried to get a route between them by utilizing the following code. However, I receive "no respond" from the function:

```
func confirmButtonClicked() {
    print("start")
    //fromLatLong is CLLocationCoordinate2D contains lag/long of the starting point.  
    //toLatLong is CLLocationCoordinate2D contains lag/long of the end point
    let origin = "\(self.fromLatLong.latitude) \(self.fromLatLong.longitude)"
    let destination = "\(self.toLatLong.latitude),\(self.toLatLong.longitude)"
    print("222")
    print(origin)
    print(destination)
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving&alternatives=true&key=MyAPIHere"

       Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
           Response in
           if Response.result.isSuccess {
               do{
                   let json =  try JSON(data: Response.data!)
                   let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue
                   print(json)
                   for i in 0 ..< routes.count{
                       let route = routes[i]
                       let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
                       let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
                       let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
                       let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                       polyline.isTappable = true
                       if i == 0{
                           polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
                           polyline.strokeWidth = 5
                           self.transferPolyline = points // SAVE THESE POINTS THEY ARE ENCODED LAT LONGS OF SUGGESTED ROUTES
                           if self.mapView != nil
                           {
                               let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path!)
                               self.mapView!.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 50.0))
                           }
                       }else{
                           polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray
                           polyline.strokeWidth = 4
                       }

                       self.polylineArray.append(polyline)
                       polyline.map = self.mapView
                   }

               }catch{
                   print("ERROR")
               }

           } else{
               print("no respond")
           }
       })
```

I had the following code before and it worked, but it only drew a straight line:

```
    func drawPath(from polyStr: String){
    let from = fromLatLong! 
    let to = toLatLong! 
    let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: polyStr)
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
    polyline.map = mapView // Google MapView


    let cameraUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: from, coordinate: to))
    mapView.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)
    let currentZoom = mapView.camera.zoom
    mapView.animate(toZoom: currentZoom - 1.4)
}
```

EDIT: 
The error message is:

```
"error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 70.xx.xxx.xxx, with empty referer",
```

"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"

EDIT (Update): The issue is solved when I change the restriction to none for testing purposes. In reality, when I launch the app, should I choose a restriction under IOS/android app or IP address? Looks like I can only choose one category.

Comment: Look at the Response object’s error and tell us what it says

Comment: See this for getting the error https://gist.github.com/perlguy99/f7f336b66ccb27fcc148b7d5bdbc9a3f

Comment: "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 70.xx.xxx.xxx, with empty referer",
  "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"

Comment: Check your google api console to make sure you haven't restricted access to a certain domain/ip you aren't accessing it from.